# GetDrawable obsolete

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using a code from GitHub to change color of icons. Unfortunately, there is one piece of the code that causes problems:

```
var d = Resources.GetDrawable(Element.Source).Mutate();
```

It tells me:

> ResourceManager.GetDrawable(Resources, string)' is obsolete: 'GetDrawable(this Resources, string) is obsolete as of version 2.5. Please use GetDrawable(this Context, string) instead.

Even though it seems to give me the solution to my problem, I still have trouble understanding what I should do.

Comment: You should be actively re-factoring the code to use the non-obsolete method signature outlined in the error message. Obsolete methods can be removed at any time with no prior warning and break your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is suggesting that you use [Context.GetDrawable()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Context.GetDrawable/p/System.Int32/) instead